# Dialog fragment not stretching out as intended

Tags: android, android-studio, user-interface

[image: Desire xml and actual emulator results]
As seen in the image abovew
I created a dialog fragment to recieve a person's input for their name and phone number but when I run the app everything seems to get very squished inside. so much so that I can't even see the cancel icon despite being there.

This is the code for the xml layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="286dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.506"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.453"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_login_rectangle" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/Name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="47dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="47dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="153dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="153dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="209dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:ems="10"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:shadowColor="#00F"
    android:text="Name"
    android:textColor="#EFB188"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/etemail"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView7"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.062"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView7"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView7"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etName"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="45dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="46dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="46dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="169dp"
    android:autofillHints=""
    android:background="@drawable/textbox1"
    android:cursorVisible="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:includeFontPadding="true"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:paddingHorizontal="10dp"
    android:textColorHighlight="#EFB188"
    android:textColorLink="#EFB188"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView7"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView7"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.479" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/Number"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="45dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="129dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="155dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="155dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="133dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:ems="10"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:shadowColor="#00F"
    android:text="Phone Number"
    android:textColor="#EFB188"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/etemail"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView7"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.062"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView7"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView7"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etNumber"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="43dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="43dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="48dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="48dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="93dp"
    android:autofillHints=""
    android:background="@drawable/textbox1"
    android:cursorVisible="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:includeFontPadding="true"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:paddingHorizontal="10dp"
    android:textColorHighlight="#EFB188"
    android:textColorLink="#EFB188"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView7"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView7"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.479" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnEnterContact"
    android:layout_width="137dp"
    android:layout_height="33dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="136dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="136dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="209dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="136dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="136dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="44dp"
    android:background="@drawable/textbox3"
    android:text="Add Contact"
    app:backgroundTint="#EFB188"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView7"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView7"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView7"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etpassword"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.726" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnCancel1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="27dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="328dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="328dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="53dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="53dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="241dp"
    android:background="@drawable/textbox3"
    android:text="X"
    app:backgroundTint="#EFB188"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView7"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView7"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView7"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etpassword"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.726" /></RelativeLayout>
```

what seems to be causing the problem here ?

Comment: If you are using Relative Layout then why are you adding constraints ??

Comment: Ah I see, I incorrectly assumed that you have to add constraints everytime no matter the layout.
Thank you !